# How to delete permanently a folder in git history

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I have a git repository and many branches.

```
master
build-app
develop
refactor-states
```

In branch **build-app**, I used to commit a **folder *release*** in repository and then deleted it.

But you know, it kept that folder forever. It make my repository so weighty ( about 200 MB).

I found the revision that had folder ***release***: **170b737**

So, can anyone could help me delete permanently **folder release**. I tried a few ways, ***filer-branch***, ***git rebase*** but I could not delete it. Please help me!!!

Comment: What `git filter-branch` did you try and what errors did you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: thanks @phd I solved the problem. I used git filter-branch and it worked

Answer (score 0):

As per the specifications shared using git rm will be would you need:

```
git rm -r folder-release
git commit -m "remove folder release"
```

The above command will delete the folder from system, so if you want to remove it from git only use the below mentioned command:

```
git rm -r --cached folder release
git commit -m "remove folder release"
```

And to push changes to remote repo

```
git push origin build-app
```

This is the procedure I used to delete a folder from remote repo using git.

Comment: I solved mine problem
In your solution, it just delete folder in your revision.
But when you find all revision of git history, it still has folder release.

Comment: Yes, from the above solution the folder will be removed in the last commit of git, in the earlier versions it will be showing that folder was committed.